# Convert string to WebControls - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

If you see the following code

```
Table tblTest = (Table)tblControl;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(text);
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
tblTest.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
htmlCode = text.ToString();
```

here i am converting a table object to string.

I'll get the output as `"<table><tr><td>item</td></tr></table>"`

Now i want to Rollback it. I am having a string and i need to convert that into WebControls.Table object. Please someone suggest some way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map of the name an HtmlControl is rendered with to the control. Then you can take the xml string sent to you and load it using `XDocument.Parse`. From there you can recursively build the control structure.

```
Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl> controlConstructor = new Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl>
                                                        {
                                                            {"table", new HtmlTable()},
                                                            {"tr", new HtmlTableRow()},
                                                            {"td", new HtmlTableCell()}
                                                        };
string xml = "<table><tr><td>item</td></tr></table>";
var htmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
Func<XElement, HtmlControl> constructHtmlStructure = null;
constructHtmlStructure = e =>
                            {
                                var control = controlConstructor[e.Name.ToString()];
                                if (e.HasElements)
                                    control.Controls.Add(constructHtmlStructure(e.Elements().Single()));
                                else
                                    control.InnerText = e.Value;
                                return control;
                            };

var structure = constructHtmlStructure(htmlDoc);
```

Is a very simple start. You'll need something much more complicated to get all controls. Note that they have a TagName property which you can use to capture all controls in building your dictionary.