# Convert string to to HtmlTableRow Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

I have a HTML row (`<tr>`) generated on client side, I want to convert the string which contains the row-cells information in a `HtmlTableRow` control. That is what I have done so far using the example on [Convert string to WebControls - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013733/convert-string-to-webcontrols-asp-net). Thanks

```
    string row = "<tr><td>item</td><td><input name=\"radio0\" type=\"radio\"/></td></tr>";
    Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl> controlConstructor = new Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl>
                                                {

                                                    {"tr", new HtmlTableRow()},
                                                    {"td", new HtmlTableCell()}
                                                };
    var htmlDoc = XElement.Parse(row);
    Func<XElement, HtmlControl> constructHtmlStructure = null;
    constructHtmlStructure = (o =>
                                {
                                    var control = controlConstructor[o.Name.ToString()];
                                    if (o.HasElements)
                                    {
                                        control.Controls.Add(constructHtmlStructure(o.Elements().Single())); //Exception: Sequence contains more than one element (When is a input item)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        control.InnerText = o.Value;
                                    }
                                    return control;
                                });

    HtmlTableRow structure = (HtmlTableRow)constructHtmlStructure(htmlDoc);
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use much simpler ways to parse your string to HtmlTableRow.

your `Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl> controlConstructor`  considers only `tr` and `td`, what about input control nested inside them?

so even if you get away through that "`sequence contains more than one element`", using a foreach loop, you will get an error `"key doesn't exist`".

and even if you manage overcome that(by adding input key in your dictionary), you cannot parse it to a `HtmlContainerControl`.

and even if you do, by updating your `Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl>` to `Dictionary<string, HtmlControl>` , you will have to think of ways to handle that input control because, for that you cannot do `control.InnerText = o.value;`

hence a much simpler way:

```
string row = "<tr><td>item</td><td><input name=\"radio0\" type=\"radio\"/></td></tr>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(row);

        HtmlTableRow tblRow = new HtmlTableRow();
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectSingleNode("tr").ChildNodes)
        {
            HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = node.InnerXml;
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Name == "input")
                {
                    if (childNode.Attributes["type"] != null)
                    {
                        switch (childNode.Attributes["type"].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            case "radio":
                                HtmlInputRadioButton rad = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                                rad.Name = childNode.Attributes["name"].ToString();
                                cell.Controls.Add(rad);

                                break;

                            ///other types of input controls
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HtmlInputButton button = new HtmlInputButton("button");
                        cell.Controls.Add(button);
                    }
                }
            }
            tblRow.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
```

as you can see, it is a very rough and strict logic: what best you can do is to come up with a recursive function, to construct your HtmlTableRow

Comment: Thanks for your time. Almost done, but i need to cast the input control to an object

Comment: in tht case, you will have to detect it, as there is no other automatic way. m updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Linq's `Single` method returns the first and only element of a sequence - if there's more than one element it throws the exception you're seeing. As your table row contains two table cells,  its `o.Elements()` method returns an enumerable with two members, and using `Single` makes it fall over.

Instead of using:

```
control.Controls.Add(constructHtmlStructure(o.Elements().Single()));
```

...use:

```
foreach(var element in o.Elements())
{
    control.Controls.Add(constructHtmlStructure(element));
}
```

That way you iterate over each of the table row's cells, and add each one to the control.

**Edit**

There's another change you need to make. Your dictionary contains exactly one `HtmlTableRow`, and exactly one `HtmlTableRow`, both already created by the time you get into `constructHtmlStructure`. Instead of having pre-existing objects (and therefore only one instance of each available) you should have your dictionary create a new instance of each type on demand.

So instead of this (adjusted for spacing):

```
var controlConstructor = new Dictionary<string, HtmlContainerControl>
{
    { "tr", new HtmlTableRow() },
    { "td", new HtmlTableCell() }
};

...

var control = controlConstructor[o.Name.ToString()];
```

...try this:

```
var controlConstructor = new Dictionary<string, Func<XElement, HtmlControl>>
{
    { "tr", o => new HtmlTableRow() },
    { "td", o => new HtmlTableCell() }
};

...

var control = controlConstructor[o.Name.ToString()].Invoke(o);
```

You'll also need a function to create an input from an `XElement`, something like this:

```
private static HtmlControl CreateInputFromElement(XElement element)
{
    // Create an appropriate HtmlInputControl...
}
```

...which you can add to your dictionary like this:

```
var controlConstructor = new Dictionary<string, Func<XElement, HtmlControl>>
{
    { "tr", o => new HtmlTableRow() },
    { "td", o => new HtmlTableCell() },
    { "input", CreateInputFromElement }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But.. it does not work structure.Cells.Count only returns 1 it could be 2

Comment: Not sure I'm following you - how do you get to call `structure.Cells.Count` if an exception is being thrown? The HTML in your question is a `tr` containing two `td`s; so the first time `constructHtmlStructure` executes, `o` (the `tr`) `.Elements()` (the `td`s) will return two elements. Which is why `Single()` throws the error it does.

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested and structure.Cells.Count returns 1 when each <td> in the string is 1 cell